# Python and Win32Com executing tasks on a remote machine (within the domain)

Tags: python, windows, win32com, windows-task-scheduler

Good morning,
I'm trying to execute a task on a remote machine within the domain using Python and Win32Com. Below is the code I'm using:

```
def exec_task(m_name, m_path,user_id):
    #Crea un'istanza dell'oggetto Task Scheduler
    scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')

    # Connetti al computer remoto
    computer_name = m_name
    scheduler.Connect(computer_name)

    # Ottieni l'oggetto Task Folder radice
    root_folder = scheduler.GetFolder('\\')

    # Crea un'istanza dell'oggetto TaskDefinition
    task_definition = scheduler.NewTask(0)

    # Imposta il nome del task
    task_definition.RegistrationInfo.Description = 'Task per catturare lo schermo del pc'
    task_definition.Settings.Enabled = True
    task_definition.Principal.UserId = user_id
    # Imposta l'azione del task per eseguire il file exe
    action = task_definition.Actions.Create(0)
    action.Path = m_path

    # Imposta i dettagli per l'esecuzione unica del task
    trigger = task_definition.Triggers.Create(1)  # Trigger di tipo OneTime
    trigger.StartBoundary = get_orario_esecuzione(1)  # Data e ora di esecuzione del task

    # Aggiungi il task alla root folder del Task Scheduler
    task_folder = root_folder.GetFolder('\\')
    task = task_folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
        'TakeScreenShot',  # Nome del task
        task_definition,  # Definizione del task
        6,  # Costante per specificare l'accesso all'utente (opzionale)
        '',  # Nome utente (opzionale)
        '',  # Password (opzionale)
        3  # Costante per specificare la registrazione del task per tutti gli utenti (opzionale)
    )

    # Esegui il task
    task.Enabled = True
    task.Run("")
```

The get_orario_esecuzione() method returns the execution time in the required format.
The execution time is the current time plus 2 minutes. The problem is that on the remote machine, the task is never executed. It is registered in the task scheduler but remains stuck in the Queued state. When I try to manually run it by right-clicking on the task and selecting "Run," the task executes successfully. Could you please let me know what could be causing this issue?

Thanks

I tried to run script many times without success. The task gets stuck on Queued status